# Can I use ear plugs while ascending or descending a mountain?

Tags: safety, health, high-altitude

Can I use ear plugs to block out noise or will my ears need to pop because of the altitude? I don’t want to get sick by using the ear plugs.

Comment: Scuba divers are recommended not to have anything in their ears whilst diving, because of equalisation and pressure, but, you're going the other way so probably no issue!

Comment: I would be wary of having them in while changing pressures (take off/landing) but once at cruise altitude no issues.  Although if you are looking for having quietness on a plane (the white noise of fans, etc. drives me nutz) I'd recommend a slim set muffs instead.  I use a set at the shooting range, very light and comfortable even in Florida heat and humidity, they cancel noise dead, and have room underneath for earbuds to still fit for music :)

Comment: @ivanivan I assume that "at altitude" means "up a high mountain", not "in an aircraft." This is Outdoors, not [travel.se].

Comment: @DavidRicherby - In that case I'll amend my comment - "you need to worry about blocking passages, etc. if pressure changes quickly". For foot powered ascent, no worries.  Really fast down hill on a bicycle or even parachuting (or is that Aviation.se?) MIGHT be fast enough to possibly cause issues.  Still recommend a set of 'letric muffs - they can amplify "quiet" noises and cut off when higher decibel levels are reached.  Listen to the birdies tweet....

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea.  If you wear earplugs, you you may not hear the sounds of dangers like rock and ice fall.

Comment: Doesn’t ear popping happen between the ear drum and the nose (middle ear) through the Eustachian tube? The space between the ear drum and the ear plug (outer ear) isn’t even in the equation.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to block out "noise" while mountaineering? You don't want to be bothered by all those noisy eagles calling?

Comment: my thoughts exactly: what sort of noise might be bothering you up on a mountain? (:

Comment: @OscarBravo I would assume they are hiking in a group where someone appreciates the sound of their own voice more than the sound of nature.

Comment: @aprilrain Noisy crowd. Too many kids. Also, it's hiking, mountaineering in itself might be less crowded. Common to find loud people while hiking.

Comment: @OscarBravo I've heard some real annoying crows when I'm trying to concentrate on building climbing anchors.

Comment: @DavidG25 Conceivably if you perfectly sealed your outer ear you might have a pressure difference form between inner and outer ear... maybe?

Comment: I know lots of people who climb with earbuds. Works great for communication when you're trying to warn your climber about the big rock falling towards his head.

Answer (score 16):

Ear popping is due to the difference in the pressure between the outer and the middle ear. Popping of ear occurs at high altitude to allow for the two pressures to equalize.

Now, there's no correlation between ear popping and altitude sickness in the first place. So, in case you are worried about AMS due to the non-popping of ears, it wont happen. Second, as Sebastiaan has already pointed out, the plugs aren't fully sealed. They wont hold the pressure as you ascend while hiking. Hence, you will have to pop your ears even if you wear your plugs.

In short, the plugs wont harm you.

Comment: +1 I've worn earplugs on airplanes many times and not had a problem.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree with the sentiment, though it should be noted that commercial airline cabin pressure matches roughly 6-8000 ft elevation while cruising. I am unsure of what elevation the OP is interested in. Regardless, Ricketyship's answer still holds.

Answer (score 8):

Earplugs are usually not 100% vacuum sealed. Even if you have custom-made ones that more or less seal (I have 2 pairs) they usually still lose the seal a bit occasionally. Certainly when you swallow, chew, yawn or do something different that moves something in your head. Combined with the extremely slow speed you’re ascending or descending (compared to an airplane or car) you really don’t have to worry about that.

Comment: Most common custom made ones have a hole (with a sound filter) which allows air to go through. When you have ones that do not allow (enough) air through, you can just wiggle them a tiny bit to break the seal (after which it will re-set.)

Answer (score 4):

Ear plugs won't help your ear from popping, because they are not build to hold the pressure as you are ascending.

Comment: If they were, and you used them at altitude, you would have a very painful experience due to the pressure on your eardrum.

Comment: You'd *probably* just have to remove them from the pain, which would allow pressure to equalize. So I think even if you wore them during liftoff/landing you'd still just get real uncomfortable and have to take them out.

Answer (score 2):

The need for your ears to pop results from a pressure differential between the middle ear and the atmosphere. The middle ear is technically outside your body (e.g., the bones in the middle ear and both sides of the ear drum are covered in skin) because it is connected to the outside via the eustachian tube. The eustachian tube is usually closed so the pressure in the middle ear doesn't respond to changes in atmospheric pressure (e.g., due to changes in elevation or altitude). When the eustachian tube opens (for example when you clear your sinuses or chew) the pressure equalizes rapidly and you feel your ears pop.

If the external ear canal is perfectly plugged and then the atmospheric pressure changes there will be a small pocket of air with a different pressure than the middle ear once the eustachian tube open and equalizes the middle ear pressure with the atmospheric pressure. This pressure differential/force between the external ear and middle ear could cause pain and a feeling of fullness like your ears still need to pop. The exact impact will depend on the volume of your middle ear, the volume of the ear trapped behind the plug, and the pressure difference.

When an audiologist performs tympanography, they create an artificial increase in the pressure in the external ear. This is a sizable 10-20 Pa change in pressure, but still less than going from sea level to the top of Everest. The changes in elevation/altitude/pressure encountered while hiking/climbing are small compared to the pressure differences encountered in an unpressurized aircraft (aircraft can climb at well over 1000 ft per minute where as [Alex Honnold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mi4iR4clDGs) and [Dan Osman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ADOK6LD70w) can only climb at 100 ft per minute), so if ear plugs are safe in unpressurized airplanes, they should be safe for climbing.

The [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/safety/pilotsafetybrochures/media/hearing.pdf) recommends ear plugs while flying. The military uses foam ear plugs (and sometimes ear plugs and muffs) in unpressurized air craft. The ear plugs do not form an air tight seal so therefore the outside pressure changes should not be a problem. If you experience discomfort like you ear not being able to pop, you can simply remove and then reinsert the plug.

If you are really concerned, or have experienced problems in the past (e.g., while flying), some companies sell [plugs designed for flying](https://cirrushealthcare.com/pages/faqs) (there may be other manufactures also and I have no experience with this product or relationship with the manufacturer).

Comment: I thought the question was purely about hiking. Not sure if flying analogy makes sense here (although many seem to have taken it that way)

Comment: @Ricketyship fair enough. I expanded my reasoning and added more information.